# Scroll function not working when overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, overflow

I have a program that should do a certain thing when you scroll upwards however, it does not respond to my scroll. I have reason to believe it is because of the

```
overflow: hidden
```

attribute I have added to the body, however, I do not want the scroll bar to show. Any idea on how to make the animation show when user scrolls downwards, but at the same time, not move the page (not actually scroll down?)

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/KFxgL/

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 1000px"></div>
<div id="up">SCROLL UP</div>
```

CSS:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
 body {
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #79CDCD;

 }
 p {
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 60px;
     color: white;
     z-index: -1;
 }
 #next {
     background-color: #79cda3;
     width: 1185px;
     position: relative;
     right: 10px;
     height: 750px;
     top: -200px;
     z-index: -1;
 }
 .animated {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 .animated.hinge {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
     -o-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     animation-name: bounceInDown;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
```

JS:

```
$('#next').fadeTo(0,0);
$(function () {
    var lastScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScroll) {     
$('p').fadeTo(350, 0); 
$('p').fadeTo(370, 1);    
$('#next').fadeTo(0,1);
$('#next').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
        } 
        lastScroll = st;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the actual event you want to react to? There is no scrolling and thus no scroll-event with overflow:hidden. Do you want to catch the mouse-wheel event (don't know what the real name is)?

Answer (score 0):

For webkit browser you can try this:
Without `overflow:hidden` in `body`

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KFxgL/9/)